# Is there any R GUI not using the client-server approach?

Tags: r, user-interface, tcp

Most people uses RStudio, at least on Windows, but it has a problem, it connects to R using TCP, through 127.0.0.1 port 8787.

That causes problems in many computers, related with the antivirus, the firewall and performamnce issues.

Sometimes they can be solved modifying the settings of the computer, but that's not always possible.

I think other GUI use the same approach.

Is there any other alternative? With R embedded in the program itself or with other kind of communication between executables.

I think the same problem goes for other GUI-scientificsoftware combinations such as Julia.

Comment: Try the tcltk R package which on standard builds of R comes with R out of the box.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck You a package to build my own GUIs but I mean a premade GUI to run R, such as Rstudio o Visual Studio+Rtools

Comment: Deducer, JGR, Rattle, Rcmdr, Red-R, RKWard, StatET

Comment: Alternately, you can change the RStudio address and port: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200552316-Configuring-the-Server

Comment: @G.Grothendieck most of them also use the same TCP communication

Answer (score 2):

You could give [R Tools for Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/visualstudio/rtvs/) a try.

> R Tools for Visual Studio (RTVS) is a free, [open-source](https://github.com/microsoft/RTVS) extension for Visual Studio 2017 and Visual Studio 2015 Update 3 (or higher), released under the MIT license. (A second open-source component called [RHost](https://github.com/microsoft/R-Host), which links to the R interpreter binaries, is released under the GNU Public License V2.)

Comment: And what would you suggest in Linux?

Comment: Does your question say anything about Linux?

Comment: I mean any platform multioperating system

Answer (score 0):

Use [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) for [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/), works on Windows, Mac, and Linux.